# File attribute access via NSFileManager more than twice as slow on iPhone 5S than iPhone 5

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c

I have looked just about everywhere for a possible answer to this strange situation, with no luck. I have 1000 files (14 bytes each, for test purposes) located in a folder inside my app's Documents directory. With the code below, I get the contents of the folder, iterate over each file URL, create a custom model object representing the file called FFFile and it to a container array. I've simplified this method for clarity.

This all works well and does what I expect, however, the strangest part is that this code takes 0.775 second to execute on an iPhone 5 and a WHOPPING 2.378 seconds on an iPhone 5S! The general assumption is that the iPhone 5S would be faster, no? Both devices are using the exact same files, folder structure, code, etc...

I don't have a very extensive understanding how a 64-bit architecture of the iPhone 5S may affect the performance of the following code, so any insight into this strange case (strange to me anyway) would be greatly appreciated. Thanks for taking a look.

UPDATE: both iPhone 5 and iPhone 5S are running iOS 7.0.3.

```
static NSArray *keys;
keys = @[
         NSURLNameKey,
         NSURLTypeIdentifierKey,
         NSURLLocalizedTypeDescriptionKey,
         NSURLIsDirectoryKey,
         NSURLCreationDateKey,
         NSURLContentModificationDateKey,
         NSURLFileSizeKey,
         ];

// url = ".../Documents/Folder/";

NSMutableArray *fileContainer = [NSMutableArray new];
NSArray *results = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] contentsOfDirectoryAtURL:url includingPropertiesForKeys:keys options:0 error:nil];
for (NSURL *url in contents) {

    NSDictionary *properties = [url resourceValuesForKeys:keys error:nil];

    FFFile *file = [[FFFile alloc] init];
    file.fileURL          = url;
    file.isDirectory      = [properties[NSURLIsDirectoryKey] boolValue];
    file.filename         = properties[NSURLNameKey];
    file.fileSize         = properties[NSURLFileSizeKey];
    file.typeIdentifier   = properties[NSURLTypeIdentifierKey];
    file.typeDescription  = properties[NSURLLocalizedTypeDescriptionKey];
    file.creationDate     = properties[NSURLCreationDateKey];
    file.modificationDate = properties[NSURLContentModificationDateKey];

    [fileContainer addObject:file];
}
```

Comment: Have you profiled the code in Instruments to see where the time is being spent?

Comment: Instruments shows that the majority of the time is spent inside -[NSFileManager contentsOfDirectoryAtURL:includingPropertiesForKeys:options:error:]

Comment: For a question like this you might have better luck asking on the proper forum at devforums.apple.com. If you're lucky one of the technical Apple guys will respond.

Comment: @dbart At the question like this I would expect to see iOs versions. As you probably know iOs 7 has some improvements at filesystem protection.

Comment: Forgot to mention, thanks for the reminder. Both iPhone 5 and iPhone 5S are running iOS 7.0.3, I've update the question as well.